# desktop (pci-express?) to usb otg adapter (linux)

Tags: usb, linux, pcie

I am looking for a pci-express usb otg adapter (or some other way) so I can do some experimenting with gadgetfs (usb device) on my desktop Linux computer. usb type c is not suitable as it uses different drivers and has a different api.

I have seen a couple of older (ACIX MCS9990, IsP1362 Pci/Linux OtG evaluation kit ) boards around that used to support it, but I have not been able to find a source for these boards.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not what you are asking but in case you don't find anything better: BeagleBone Black is a Linux board which has gadgetfs, although with quite slow ARM processor.

Comment: yes, I have used this and the Raspberry pi zero (w) however I have had a few problems with some of the software I am playing with running on these platforms.